# Display future posts?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, date-time, publish

Is there a way to display posts, scheduled for the future?

I want to use the published data as an event date and time, which is obviously in the future. I still would like to use these posts for a loop, and for single pages.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $args = array(
    'post_status' => "future",
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC'
     );
$yourLoop = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

- `'post_status' => 'draft'` to receive all posts that are not published.
- `'order' => 'DESC'` to sort from highest (first) value to the lowest
- `'orderby' => 'date'` to sort by post date

Get

- the current date for comparison with [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) or the built in [`current_time()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time) function
- the posts year with [`get_the_time()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time)

then compare if the post is in the future and - if so - display it.

*Maybe there are easier ways to do this, but this is the fastest guide to a solution I could come up with.*